# Dates in Excel formatted as MM-DD-YYYY but Excel recognised as DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a date column in my spreadsheet that is not sorting properly because some dates are in MMDDYYYY HH:MIN format while others are in DDMMYYYY HH:MIN format, and Excel recognises all as MMDDYYYY HH:MIN. How do standardise? How do I have Excel recognise the dates as DDMMYYYY HH:MIN, and convert MMDDYYYY HH:MIN (which are currently seen as DDMMYYYY)?

I tried to convert date to text using TEXT() but now I am stuck. DATE() doesn't allow me to specify the format I am converting from.

Comment: Are there dashes in the dates or not?

Comment: Depending on your locale setting, excel will try to interpret any entered date as either dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy.  It's not always successful in doing that...  Where are the dates from?

Comment: the question is : how does your data get to excel? Is it manually typed or does it come from a database? Make sure you read [this](http://excelsemipro.com/2011/06/regional-date-formats-in-excel/) - it will show you [how to manually adjust the locale settings for excel](http://excelsemipro.com/2011/06/regional-date-formats-in-excel/). Also, sorting date isn't usually something you want to do using excel's built in features because it simply doesn't apply to all date formats. You may want to implement your own sorting method i.e. splitting the date elements and sorting by the pieces.

Comment: A supporting example to what I have just said would be take 2 columns with dates as DD/MM/YYYY and the other one MM/DD/YYYY put a filter on and sort it in ascending order - it will help you realize that excel doesn't properly sort it.

Comment: There are dashes. Sorry if it wasn't clear. The dates are from a program which has recovered all my SMSes from my Windows Mobile phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in some of the comments above, the regional settings of the computer can affect the way in which Excel deals with dates and, some times, can provoke difficult-to-fix situations.

The first solution for your problem is changing the (date) format of the cells; as far as I understand that you will be affecting the cells via VBA, it is better to rely on VBA code to make sure that everything will be OK.

You can do a simple test to see how the date-format-modifications behave: put some dates in column A and the same ones in column B (i.e., cell B1: "=A1", cell B2 "=A2", etc.) and execute the following code from VBA:

```
Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm"
Range("B:B").NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm"
```

If there is no problem, you would see the months in different positions in both columns. In that case, you might rely on this kind of code to make sure that the date format is the one you want.

If this test is not passed successfully, I recommend you to rely on text rather than on dates to avoid problems: set the format of all the columns to text (`.NumberFormat = "@"` in VBA), parse the given values (day, month, etc.), treat them as dates in your calculations and convert them back into text when writing to Excel (after that you might do some experiments and see if converting the given cell into date delivers the behaviour you want).

Comment: Welcome. I did have some problems myself with date formats in Excel in the past and I know how frustrating it can become.